# c# tuple list multiple sort

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a three-dimensional tuple array:

```
var CountList = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
```

The sorting required is numerically ascending on the first int, then numerically descending on the second int, so

```
5, 4, 7
4, 5, 6
5, 2, 3
3, 5, 2
2, 4, 1
2, 6, 4
```

becomes

```
2, 6 ,4
2, 4, 1
3, 5, 2
4, 5, 6
5, 4, 7
5, 2, 3
```

Is there a way of specifying further search functions for List.Sort(), or do I need to split the information out to separate lists, perform the descending sort on each group, then add the individual list items to a "master list" in the desired ascending order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
CountList = CountList
    .OrderBy(t => t.Item1)
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.Item2)
    .ToList();
```

The less comprehensible but possibly more efficient way using [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
CountList.Sort(
(t1, t2) =>
{
    int res = t1.Item1.CompareTo(t2.Item1);
    return res != 0 ? res : t2.Item2.CompareTo(t1.Item2);
});
```

`List.Sort` sorts the original list instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Enumerable.ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

```
var Sorted = CountList.OrderBy(l=>l.Item1)
                      .ThenByDescending(l => l.Item2)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
List<Tuple<int, int, int>> Sorted
  = CountList.OrderBy( iTuple => iTuple.Item1 )
             .ThenByDescending( iTuple => iTuple.Item2 )
             .ToList();
```

or implement a custom comparer to obtain a [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 0):

Sort has an overload that takes a Comparison parameter.

```
CountList.Sort((t1, t2) => {
        int c = t1.Item1.CompareTo(t2.Item1);
        if (c != 0) return c;
        c = t1.Item2.CompareTo(t2.Item2);
        return -c;
    }
);
```