# c# Group and then Sort list of tuple <T1,T2,T3>

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, tuples

I'm new to C# and I want to sort my collection of `List<Tuple<int, string, int>>`

The user inputs data for example:

```
T1   T2   T3
1  abbc   3             
1  becky  5           
1  betty  56           
2  Olivia 6             
2  abbc   3            
2  becky  5           
3  Olivia 675
```

I would like the sort list to look like;

```
 ID = 1 { abbc,3|becky,5|betty,56 }        
 ID = 2 { Olivia,6|abbc,3|becky,5 }          
 ID = 3 { Olivia,675 }
```

please help i'm really stuck :)

Comment: You can create a class that inherits from List<Tuple<int, string, int>> and implements ISortable. That way you can call the Sort method on your new class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# tuple list multiple sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991802/c-sharp-tuple-list-multiple-sort)

Comment: On what basis, you are sorting?

Comment: @helpme -  By your wanted output he it seems like you first want to group the results and only then sort. Is that correct?

Comment: @GiladGreen  yes, sorry I'm so bad with explaining myself

Comment: @helpme - check my answer

Comment: @Tom - see helpme's clarification - it isn't a duplication of that question

Answer (score 11):

It looks more like you want to `Group` your items and then `Order` by the first int (`Id`):

```
List<Tuple<int, string, int>> data = new List<Tuple<int, string, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(1,"abbc",3),
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(1,"becky",5),
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(1,"betty",56),
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(2,"Olivia",6),
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(2,"abbc",3),
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(2,"becky",5),
    new Tuple<int, string, int>(3,"Olivia",675),
};

var result = data.GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
                 .Select(group => new { Id = group.Key, Values = group.Select(item => new { item.Item2, item.Item3 }).ToList() })
                 .OrderBy(item => item.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: @helpme - Did this help you?

Comment: lol, I can't say for OP, but you've made my day with the above comment :)

Comment: @IvanStoev - hahaha ya! made me laugh myself ;P

Comment: @GiladGreen I have a similar problem couldn't find a solution to it